# Identifying JS React CSS Selector using Scrapy

Tags: css, reactjs, scrapy

I am trying to use Scrapy on a [Reddit page](https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/) using the CSS Selector to identify an element. What I am seeing is something different than a traditional CSS selector, it is a randomly mix of numbers/letters as a method of an h3 element. I suspect its something to do with JS react. What I ultimately am trying to do is pull out the text of a title.

Here is what the Firefox WebDev tools inspector returns as the CSS Path for a title:

```
html body div#2x-container div._1VP69d9lk-Wk9zokOaylL div div#SHORTCUT_FOCUSABLE_DIV._1gsAk1ihQliBnDybgyjghy div.SubredditVars-r-gameofthrones div._1nxEQl5D2Bx2jxDILRHemb div div.f3kbjo-0.jsptSt div.f3kbjo-1.gHIJbE div._1vyLCp-v-tE5QvZovwrASa div.u1x7p5-0.iYtPfj div.rpBJOHq2PR60pnwJlUyP0 div div div#t3_cmy9rm._1oQyIsiPHYt6nx7VOmd1sz._1RYN-7H8gYctjOQeL8p2Q7.scrollerItem._3Qkp11fjcAw9I9wtLo8frE._1qftyZQ2bhqP62lbPjoGAh.Post.t3_cmy9rm div._1poyrkZ7g36PawDueRza-J._11R7M_VOgKO1RJyRSRErT3 div._2FCtq-QzlfuN-SwVMUZMM3._3wiKjmhpIpoTE2r5KCm2o6.t3_cmy9rm div.y8HYJ-y_lTUHkQIc1mdCq._2INHSNB8V5eaWp4P0rY_mE a.SQnoC3ObvgnGjWt90zD9Z._2INHSNB8V5eaWp4P0rY_mE div._2SdHzo12ISmrC8H86TgSCp._3wqmjmv3tb_k-PROt7qFZe h3._eYtD2XCVieq6emjKBH3m
```

With what is the CSS selector of the element I am trying to identify:

```
h3._eYtD2XCVieq6emjKBH3m
```

For reference, on stackoverflow If I were to get the body text element, the CSS selector I would identify would be:

```
div.post-text
```

Can anyone shed any light on what Reddit is doing with the CSS selectors and why they are different. And proper form for returning the element?

Thanks.

P.S. [this is for reference what I want to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56692345/targeting-ids-with-scrapy-css-selector), but I'd like a more in-depth under-the-hood explanation of what Reddit is doing. Also, if it's not React, please enlighten me to what it is.

Comment: Reddit frontend is written in react.If you use the reactive dev tools you will see the blue icon next to the url bar

Comment: Don't use css selectors on React websites, classNames will change whenever website is updated. Use https://old.reddit.com/ to scrape data, no react, so you can just read the html to get data. Right now I think you are using splash or something the render React. New reddit's React code is most likely using jss so random classNames are generated dynamically.

Comment: On any reddit link replace `www` with `old` to view the old reddit. Instead of `https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/` scrape `https://old.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/`. btw  I am pretty sure Reddit provides an API or something like that which you can use in python to get data in structured format instead of relying on scraping.

Comment: See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html